When do filtered colimits commute with finite products in Top
It is well known that filtered colimits commute with finite products (more generally any finite limit). This is not the case in general in Top due to Top not being cartesian closed. My question is is there a characterisation as to when these do commute?
Specifically my question is given filtered diagrams in Top when is $\text{colim}_{(i,j)}(X_i\times Y_i) = \text{colim}_i(X_i)\times \text{colim}_j(Y_j)$?
I managed to show that if the morphisms of the diagrams are open maps of topological spaces, then the colimit and product commute. Is this a neccesary condition or are there other situations where this happens?

I don't think the failure of cartesian closure is relevant. Filtered colimits commute with finite limits in the category of models of any algebraic theory (groups, rings, modules) and these are almost never cartesian closed.
